# Creating Markdown File from Menu in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, install.packages

Using R Studio Version 1.0.44
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

I need to create an R Markdown file from the menu. I select File->New File->R Markdown...

It tells me I have to update markdown and knitr packages. I click okay, "yea, go ahead and do that" and it has an error (popup screen that helpfully goes away before I can tell what the problem is).

So I tried to do this manually from the R studio console:

```
install.packages("markdown") 
install.packages("knitr")
```

When I do this, there is no problem reported....however, when I try to create the R markdown file, I get the same message commanding me to install required packages.

I found a note online that mentioned you have to install markdown from github.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

Then I get a completely different message by trying to do this:

```
Error: Command failed(65535)
```

I sense I'm going down the rat hole here. Has anyone had this problem and fixed it?  I just need to be able to create a markdown file using that menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are attempting to install or update a package that is in use (or has a dependency in use) it will ask you if you want to refresh the session. I suspect that is the message you are getting as you don't say exactly what the error is. However, it does not just go away (You have to select Yes or No).

Have you attempted to restart Rstudio and then install the packages?

The `Error: Command failed(65535)` is a Windows error it seems and [is not related to devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/857); perhaps a missing dll file.

I do not recall having to install markdown from GitHub. It is installed as a dependency of rmarkdown. I removed rmarkdown, markdown and devtools and then reinstalled on a fresh session with the `install.packages` command; no issues.

I suspect this is more a Windows error than an R error.

Comment: Yes. I had tried those things.  However, you gave me the missing bit.  All I had to do is install.packages("rmarkdown") in addition to markdown and it worked fine.  If the message panel hadn't disappeared so quickly, I might have been able to discern that.  Thanks.